# Set N/A (Not Available) on TextView from XML

Tags: android, xml, string, textview

Hello guys i have lots of different `String` and `TextView` on xml. I want to show **N/A** (Not Available) option on `TextView` if the string are null or blank. I can do it by using `if` condition but this is very time consuming in my case, please help me to get out from this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `yourTextView.setText(isEmpty(yourValue) ? "N/A" : yourValue);`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein after adding TextUtils.isEmpty it perfectly works for me. Is there any method to do this task using XML ??

Comment: Maybe the software which generates the xml could make it for you. Once generate, only an xsl transformation could render it on a web browser correctly. Or what you do in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:hint="N/A"` in the TextView layout.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, set the default text for each textView as N/A by using:

```
android:text="N/A"
```

and then if that string has a value you need to set, in your java file, just add:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewID);
myTextView.setText(myValue);
```

Hope I helped :D